# How to improve the performance of database queries of an django sites running with SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, django, azure

I am working on a project that is using django 1.11.0, SQL server and azure as deployment site. It takes longer than the actual execution time shown on console.

We tried to follow django best practices for better performance. But still  it is rarely acceptable due to performance issue.

Can anyone suggest me how could I improve the performance to reduce the view response time? Currently it takes 6 seconds in view for response while in console it takes only 1.2 second for 1444 records. 
How can I reduce the difference between console time and view response time?

Comment: It's impossible to answer such a vague and generic question. wrt/ the DB part itself, problems can come from the schema, the queries, the communication between the django process and the DB server, and eventually the dataset itself. Also, it looks like you have issues outside the DB part (6s vs 1.2s), so part of your problem is probably at the view / template level and possibly with the front http server. In all cases, the first step is to profile your code to find out where the real bottlenecks are, and from experience they rarely are where we expect them.